# flutter: record a video that has same duration as animated webp

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, video-recording, webp

**what I'd like to do:**
I would like to record a video using Flutter's CameraController that has the same duration as an animated webp. On top of my screen, the animated webp is playing and below there is a CameraPreview() widget that records whatever my camera catches. This recorded video's duration should be exact as long as the animated webp's duration.

**what I've tried so far:**
Since Giphy offers not only a webp-version, but also an mp4-version, I downloaded the mp4 version and used ffmpeg to get the duration of that file. 
I then used a timer and called VideoController.stopVideoRecording() after this duration automatically after VideoController.startVideoRecording().

**what I'd expect to happen:**
I'd expect this recorded video to be as long as the animated webp. Unfortunately, it's not.

**So, my question is:**
Do you guys have any idea how I could manage to record a video with same duration as an animated webp?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sort of found what the issue is: Webp (and also Gifs) in Flutter are played slower than in browsers. Dont know if that is the case for all webps and gifs, but the ones I tested are all animated faster in a desktop-browser than in flutter. So, animation time of those webp is not the same as playing-time of the respective .mp4 file.
I use those mp4-versions now instead and that does the job.